# login page is giving alert of invalid credentials,but my api is returning the correct info

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, web-frontend, react-navigation-v6

As soon as my trying to login the else part of the code is running
I tried to `console.log` and the server is sending the correct info but still alert is getting triggered
I have given images of console for the reference

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HhJs.jpg)

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"

const Login = (props) => {
    const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({email: "", password: ""}) 
    let navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({email: credentials.email, password: credentials.password})
        });
        const json = await response.json()
        console.log(json);

**//Main Error**

        if (json.success){
            // Save the auth token and redirect
            localStorage.setItem('token', json.AuthToken);
            navigate("/"); 

        }
        else{
            alert("Invalid credentials");
        }
    }

    const onChange = (e)=>{
        setCredentials({...credentials, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form  onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <label htmlFor="email" className="form-label">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" className="form-control" value={credentials.email} onChange={onChange} id="email" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" />
                    <div id="emailHelp" className="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <label htmlFor="password" className="form-label">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" value={credentials.password} onChange={onChange} name="password" id="password" />
                </div>

                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ1JT.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HhJs.jpg
```

Comment: The property in the image is `sucess` and you're checking for `success`

Comment: Yep it is successful but code is not processing the IF part and it is not saving in local storage

Comment: What I mean is that if you take a better look at the image, you'll see that the object looks like this: `{ sucess: true, .... }` (`sucess`, only one `c`) and the condition is `if (json.success) { .. }` `success` with two `c`s.

Comment: thanks alot it finally worked